# For any given $k$, show that an integer $n$ can be represented as: $n={m_1 \choose 1} + {m_2 \choose 2} + \cdots + {m_k \choose k}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

For any given $k$, show that an integer $n$ can uniquely be represented as: $$n={m_1 \choose 1} + {m_2 \choose 2} + \cdots + {m_k \choose k}$$ where $0 < m_1 < m_2 < \cdots < m_k$.

My hunch is to find what the $m_i$'s must be, since the representation is unique.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system

Comment: It's not true, for $n<k$. You need $0\leq m_1<m_2\dots$ to allow for $n<k$. And you probably want $n$ non-negative, too.

Comment: Related: See the discussion of the "squashed order:" https://books.google.com/books?id=WCQkAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA113&ots=S2Z4DFBwZp&dq=squashed%20order&pg=PA113#v=onepage&q=squashed%20order&f=false